# How to set image source from SQLite in a ListView

Tags: android, string, sqlite, listview, imageview

I've a Listview populated with data from a SQLite data base with this code:

```
String[] from = new String[]{manager.CN_NAME, manager.CN_COLORFRUTO};
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
```

Works great. But I also want to set the image source from the database.

I've seen in a video that it could be done like this

```
String[] from = new String[]{manager.CN_NAME, manager.CN_COLORFRUTO, manager.CN_IMAGE};
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, R.id.imageView2};
```

But as a result of doing this, the imageview doesn't show anything (not even the default @drawable/image that it is set in android:src="@drawable/image")

I've searched a lot and tried many ways to do this, but nothing has worked to me.
I've tried with setImageResource, but the imageview is in the layout "lista1" and this code works for another layout: setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

Here it is the whole code of the activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private DataBaseManager manager;
Cursor cursor;

private EditText etBuscar;
private Cursor c;
private ListView lista;
private TextView tv;
private ImageButton bt;
private ImageView imageView;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    manager = new DataBaseManager(this);
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    bt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);

    String[] from = new String[]{manager.CN_NAME, manager.CN_COLORFRUTO, manager.CN_IMAGE};
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, R.id.imageView2};

    cursor = manager.cargarCursorFrutos();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.lista1,cursor,from,to,0);        
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    [...]
```

Edit:
This is what R.layout.lista1 XML looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="Descripción del contenido de la imagen"
    android:src="@drawable/berries1"

    />



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is R.layout.activity_base XML, which has a search edit text and a image button to search in the listview:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

**Edit2:**
I've found something about ViewBinder. But I can't implement the examples I've seen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your `R.layout.lista1` look like? Add the XML to your question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969276/listview-containing-image-using-sqlite-database-in-android/24969366#24969366

Comment: I've tried that, but as I tried to explain, the class sets the layout for R.layout.activity_base (the listview layout), and the "imageview" is in R.layout.lista1 (the layout for each row of the listview), so I haven't been able to make "setImageResource" work cos it's in a different layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter :

```
   public class YourViewBinder  implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

            if(view.getId()==R.id.imageView2) {
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourdrawable);
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
    }
```

In your Activity set the adapter for the listview

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new YourViewBinder());
```

Comment: I finally changed the way of doing my proyect, and had no opportunity to try this, but it seems that it would have worked.
Sorry for taking so long to answer and thanks a lot for your answer.